# How to keep encapsulation?

Tags: c#, graph, architecture, encapsulation

Let's imagine a graph structure. Each node has inputs and outputs and one node's output can be connected to another node input by a connection. Something like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public IReadOnlyList<Input> Inputs
    {
        get { ... }
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Output> Outputs
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}

public class Connection
{
    public Connection(Input input, Output output)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to store this structure in some kind of file. If I want to store the connection though, I have to get information, which which node is owner of input and output - otherwise I won't be able to restore this later.

The easiest way is simply to store node in input and output. But that IMO breaks encapsulation as input and output shouldn't know anything about node, which uses them. Another solution is bruteforce - search through all nodes to find one, which owns these elements. But it's damn dirty, I don't like this solution.

How can I solve this without breaking encapsulation?

Answer (score 1):

Given a connection is as much between two nodes as it is between an input and an output, it would probably be reasonable to store the two nodes in the Connection object as well as the input and output. That is:

```
public class Connection
{
    public Connection(Node inNode, Input input, Node outNode, Output output)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is more constructor arguments than would be ideal, but the way you've described the Connection class does suggest it should know which nodes it's connecting as well as which inputs and outputs to use.

Comment: Looks reasonable. I have to give it a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your code, this is what comes to my mind:

[image: Graph]
(The boxes represent the connection object)

If you don't want to change your code, this would be a possible structure for the file:

```
#CONNECTIONS
0 16
1 21
2 20
3 17
4 18
5 19
6 12
7 14
8 15
9 13
10 11
#NODES
0 16 12 14,9 10
1 11 13,8 2 7
3 17 21, 6
4 18,0
5 15,5 3
6 19 20,1 4
```

The `#CONNECTIONS` section:

stores the id of the input-output edges. You can add there more information about the edge,of course(weight...etc). Something like

```
10 11 0.4238 82 "weight"
```

The `#NODES` section:

```
node_id <inputs>*,<outputs>*
```

For loading it, you can store the edges in a dictionary, and you can add them to the corresponding node later.